# Radius of convergence for binomial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, binomial-theorem

The question is simple: determine the radius of convergence for the given series. 
I have done this for other problems using the following rule which our book described:

If the given series is 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{k}x^k $$

Than the radius of convergence can be found using the following limit:

$$ R = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{c_{k}}{c_{k+1}} $$

The series I struggle with is given by:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{2k}{k} x^k$$

This supposed answer to this question is that $R = \frac{1}{4}$, but my solution find $R$ to be $+\infty$. Here is my solution:

I rewrote the binomial formula using substitution $ \binom{2k}{k} = \frac{(2k)!}{k!k!} $, and plugged this in as $c_{k}$:

$$ R = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{(2k)!}{k!k!}}{\frac{(2k + 1)!}{(k + 1)!(k + 1)!}} $$ 
$$ R = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(2k)!(k + 1)!(k + 1)!}{(2k + 1)!k!k!} $$

Some term can be simplified to:

$$ R = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(k + 1)(k + 1)}{2k + 1} $$
$$ R = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{k^2 + 2k + 1)}{2k + 1} $$

I now take the limit of the highest order terms

$$ R = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{k^2}{2k} $$ 
$$ R = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{k}{2} $$
$$ R = \frac{\infty}{2} $$
$$ R = \infty $$

As I said the supposed answer is $\frac{1}{4}$ and I think it is just a calculation mistake, but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks in advance, 
Matthias

Comment: The radius of convergence normally is used for power series, but there is no $x$ in your series.  Is something missing?

Comment: Forgot to add it, It has now been edited.

Comment: You also have an arithmetic mistake when you calculate the ratio.  You should get $(k+1)^2 / ((2k+1)(2k+2))$.

Comment: Yes, that is also what Bernard explained :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miscalculated $c_{k+1}$: it is $\dfrac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)!(k+1)!}$, so you obtain
$$\frac{c_k}{c_{k+1}}= \frac{(2k)!}{(2k+2)!}\, \frac{(k+1)!\,(k+1)!}{k!\,k!}= \frac{(k+1)^2}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\sim_\infty \frac{k^2}{(2k)^2}=\frac14.$$

Comment: That explains! Thank you!